How precise does Super Heavy's tower landing have to be?
What is the position and velocity range it needs to fit in, to be safely caught by the Orbital Launch Mount?

I don't know and I doubt anyone outside of SpaceX really knows. But position accuracy must be in the region of +/-0.5m. Velocity probably needs to be less than 1m/s (I suspect that the catching arms could move downwards to help if required). An additional point that may be of interest - the grid fins are not designed to take the weight of Superheavy, but maybe in the event of a failure they might be strong enough to prevent total disaster even if they were badly damaged as a result.

@Slarty - The arms can rotate sideways as we see when they are lifting the booster or ship. If the system is able to rotate the arms some amount of distance after the booster has arrived into position, then I think it might require only a few meters of accuracy on the part of the booster to get into position for the "catch". How fast the arms can move would be a factor. However if during landing the arms can only swing closed from whatever position they are in at landing time, then the 0.5 m estimate would probably be about right.

@Steve Pemberton Yes that is a good point.

This is the fastest we've seen the chopsticks move to date: link
This is pretty recent so it's probably related to catching tests.
It's currently unclear if they want to adjust the catching arms to the booster, or just keep them mostly stationary and guide the booster into the right spot. But with this speed it looks like the arms could compensate by a few meters sideways if necessary. Front-back there's already leeway of several meters. Up-down probably not very much, but that's easy for booster to do.

Looking at the current hardware the booster has lifting pins that appear to be about three feet long, based on looking at this photo of the lifting pins in comparison to the twelve foot long grid fins.

Screenshot from SpaceX promotional video
Elon Musk has recently indicated the possibility of attempting a booster catch on the next test flight, so it would seem that the existing pins are what will be used for the landing attempt, as I don't think anything different has been observed on upcoming boosters that are in development.
That being the case, three feet would seem to be the position accuracy required if the booster was landing on arms that remain fixed in place during the landing.


However the arms are not fixed, during landing the Mechazilla "chopstick" arms will be spread out, and Starship will move into  position in front of the launch tower and then hover. The chopstick arms will then swing together underneath the lifting pins, and then Starship will lower itself onto the arms. I don't think it has been stated by SpaceX the position accuracy that will be required for Starship to get into position for the arm movement. Although some estimates could possibly be made based on the dimensions of the booster and the Mechazilla arms and what has been observed about their range of motion.

(author: @LunarCaveman via X)

The post you used your picture from is wrong. SpaceX does not plan to use the cape Canaveral launch tower at LC-39A as the arms are too short to even reach out to the launch mount and this cannot even stack it there.

@LawnHollanderLawn - the diagram is just for the purpose of illustration to help visualize the possible motions of the arms in relation to the lifting pins, even though we dont know what their actual range of motion will be during the landing. Or whether for example they will start rotating if needed as the booster approaches, or will the arms only start moving after the booster has nulled all of its motion and has started hovering. I don't think we even know for sure if the arms will rotate at all, and that will make a big difference on required booster accuracy.

One thing that's concerning with this tower design is the arms cannot rotate 360°, while wind and gusts are free to do so.

I thought that the arms could be aligned with the prevailing wind, like a windsock, to always offer the same catching conditions.

@user721108 - I'm guessing that the approach path to the tower will always be the same regardless of wind direction, as there are a lot of other factors involved. Wind speed and direction might however be a constraint for launch if it creates unsafe conditions for a catch.

The range of Super heavy to be caught by the OLM is an ellipse with its width shorter than its length (since the OLM's arm cannot catch it by 1 side) and the velocity will have 2 vectors; vertical, and horizontal which is greatly limited due to the arms only catching the top of the booster. https://x.com/LunarCaveman/status/1557314480551378944/photo/1
This is where the dimensions of the OLM'S chopsticks.
Here are the vectors:

Horizontal velocity: less than 5 m/s
Vertical velocity: Less than 12 m/s
Range from center: Less than 5 m left and right or 10 m forward and back


You’ve got the same link to a phot twice, but haven’t embedded the image from either. If you need help getting the image embedded, you can see how Steve Pemberton did it here, or I’m willing to help, but it’s unclear whether you mean to share both photos or just one of the two, so you’d need to indicate which of the two (or both) you mean to use
